# Perl "Too many errors" Error

Tags: perl, runtime-error

this is my first time coding in Perl and I'm having issues getting it to run.

When trying to run it, it just says `Too many errors`, which doesn't really help when you're starting out coding.

Here is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use Modern::Perl;

print "Gimme Number 1:" ;
my $num1=<>;

print "Gimme Number 2:" ;
my $num2=<>;

print "Gimme Number 3:" ;
my $num3=<>;

my $add=$num1 + $num2 + $num3;
my $muti=$num1 * $num2 * $num3;
my $div=$num1 / $num3;
my $rad=$num3 % $num2;
my $sub=$num2 - $num3;
my $big=$num1 * $num2/$num4;

print "ADD:$add";
print "MUL:$muti";
print "DIV:$div";
print "MOD:$rad";
print "SUB:$sub";
print "EQT:$big";
```

What am I doing wrong? Thanks.

Comment: What errors did you get?

Comment: "too many errors" I'm legit being serious... like that what is called...

Comment: "X has too many errors" indicates the parser got *really* confused, but it shouldn't have on that simple code.  And it should have told you `Global symbol "$num4" requires explicit package name` before that. What version of Perl are you using (run `perl -v`) and on what operating system? Are you using some sort of IDE?

Answer (score 2):

Running a compile check `perl -cw filename.pl` on your code yields:

```
Global symbol "$num4" requires explicit package name at foo line 20.
```

Which suggests that you should declare `$num4` and add a input line for it at the top, or as Schwern suggests, that `$num4` is a typo for `$num3`.

Comment: More likely it's a typo for `$num3`.

Comment: Either way, the compiler is unhappy!

Comment: Fixed that still getting an error                                                                                                                            syntax error at line 7, near "print"
Execution aborted due to compilation errors.

Answer (score 0):

Try checking for syntax correctness in cmd `perl -c <filename.pl>`
Always use these 2 lines in the starting 
`use strict; 
 use warnings;
 your perl code goes here`. These will help you to show if any errors or warnings are there when you check for syntax.

Comment: I did not know that Thanks

Answer (score 0):

i believe you have used `$new4` instead of $new3 or some other variable.
The line which is giving issue is

`my $big=$num1 * $num2/$num4;`

please update the code after replacing the above , so we can make your first attempt successful